# "metaMDS" can do both PCoA and NMDS?

Tags: r, vegan

I am learning how to do PCoA, but when I test `metaMDS`, the result is different.

```
NMDS<-metaMDS(eurodist)
plot(NMDS)
```

[image]

```
NMDS<-metaMDS(as.dist(eurodist))
plot(NMDS$points)
```

[image]

http://www.davidzeleny.net/anadat-r/doku.php/en:pcoa_nmds this is where I learned.
I thought `MDS` is for PCoA, while `NMDS` is not, dose the above sample mean `metaMDS` can do both `MDS` and `NMDS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first problem is that `plot(NMDS$points)` is not creating the plot correctly; you *must* draw the plot with equal axis scaling or aspect ratio of 1. If you draw the plot correctly by hand then there is no difference:

```
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
plot(metaMDS(eurodist)$points, asp = 1, main = "aps = 1")
plot(metaMDS(eurodist), main = "plot.metaMDS")
layout(1)
```

[image]

There are good reasons why we provide S3 methods for things like `scores` and `plot` so you don't need to remember the details. If you go off piste, you do need to sweat the details.

This should now answer your main question; **no** `metaMDS()` does *not* do *principal coordinates analysis. If you want principal coordinates analysis, see `?capscale`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But there was another problem about PCoA (Principal Coordinate Analysis). This method is also known as MDS (Metric Multidimensional Scaling).  http://www.davidzeleny.net/anadat-r/doku.php/en:pcoa_nmds    Since `metaMDS()` does not do PCoA, why do you show the "MDS1" or "MDS2" in x and y when using `plot(metaMDS(eurodist)$points`?

Comment: Those are the names on the matrix; we should perhaps change them to be `NMDSx` to be consistent with the plot, but you realised the M in MDS is for *multi*, not *metric*? [MDS is a generic term for a set of methods that map (dis)similarities into a low dimensional space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling). Metric MDS and non-metric MDS are just two flavours of the MDS class. Some people play a little fast and loose with terminology. So it's not wrong to name the column of scores `MDSx`, but it is perhaps a little confusing and certainly inconsistent with the `plot` method.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I need some basic knowledge to reflect on that. I really appreciate your information. I am learning Ordination methods [here](http://ordination.okstate.edu/).  By the way, is there any difference between `capscale` and `cmdscale` since both were `PCoA`?

Comment: Hello, Gravin Simpson. I think I got the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613046/multidimensional-scaling)